# explicit qualification in declaration of 'std::cout'

Tags: c++, iostream, explicit

The problem is really strange for me.

The code is as simple as possible:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is just helloworld as it is created from standart cpp project.
I am sure it was worked. But after some time (really don't remember what have chaged...) I got an error:

```
error: explicit qualification in declaration of 'std::cout'
   extern ostream std::cout;  /// Linked to standard output
```

funny thing that is not in the project  but inside   iostream

some help? ^_^

.new information.:
I was building boost library and for many of files I am getting the same error: explicit qualification in declaration of 'std::cout'

I use MinGW

Comment: What you posted is fine. You have code somewhere that you are not posting. If there is any doubt then create a new project and paste exactly that you've posted here into it. Then see if you still get the error.

Comment: Maybe you changed the project settings in your `IDE`?

Comment: My first program code  in c++ :) :)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Maybe related, but perhaps too fancy for a C++ beginner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461832/explicit-qualification-in-declaration

Comment: Christopher, It is a new project. The problem that I didn't change anything in it but getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanations that come to mind are:

1. Someone modified the standard header (accidentally?), replacing the original

   ```
   extern ostream cout;
   ```

   with incorrect

   ```
   extern ostream std::cout;
   ```
2. Someone defined a macro named `cout` as `std::cout`, most likely in the compiler's command line. E.g.

   ```
   -Dcout=std::cout
   ```

   See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc5be8c7d99fed53 for example.

Comment: You are the man! Thank you!
Can you imagine, I was using refactoring to change cout with std::cout... and it was also changed inside of iostream... 
Stupid user)))